# How to use HTML string in React Native?

Tags: html, react-native

I have one constant variable where I am holding a HTML string that is nothing but a button. Now I want to use that button in React Native app with click event and some CSS.

My code:-

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View ,TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
import HTMLView from 'react-native-htmlview';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    console.log("checking log...");
  }
     render() {
     const btn = `<button onClick="alert("Hey");">Hey click me</button>                  `
    return (
      // Try setting `justifyContent` to `center`.
      // Try setting `flexDirection` to `row`.
      <View style={{
       flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor:'red'
      }}>
       <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}}>          
       </View>           
        <HTMLView value={btn}/>    
      </View>
    );
  }    
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
   backgroundColor:'red',
   borderColor:'black',
    color: 'white', // make links coloured pink
  },
});
```

Comment: What problem _specifically_ are you having trouble with?

Comment: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localised guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).